# Forward declaration not working in c++. It says initialization of incomplete type

Tags: c++

I am learning design patterns and I am trying to implement builder pattern. For this purpose I am compiling below code with "clang++ -std=c++17" but I am getting error "error: initialization of incomplete type 'HtmlBuilder'" where I am returning in static function HtmlElement::build. How to solve this issue?

```
class HtmlBuilder;

class HtmlElement
{
    friend class HtmlBuilder;
    string name, text;
    vector<HtmlElement> elements;
    const size_t indent_size = 2;
    HtmlElement() {}
    HtmlElement(const string &name, const string &text): name(name), text(text) {}

public:
    string str(int indent = 0) const
    {
        ostringstream oss;
        string i(indent_size*indent, ' ');
        oss << i << "<" << name << ">" << endl;

        if (text.size() > 0)
        {
            oss << string(indent_size * (indent + 1), ' ') << text << endl;
        }

        for (const auto& e: elements)
        {
            oss << e.str(indent + 1);
        }

        oss << i << "</" << name << ">" << endl;

        return oss.str();
    }

    static HtmlBuilder build(const string& root_name)
    {
        return {root_name};
    }
};

class HtmlBuilder
{
    HtmlElement root;

public:
    HtmlElement build()
    {
        return root;
    }

    HtmlBuilder(const string& root_name)
    {
        root.name = root_name;
    }

    HtmlBuilder& add_child(const string& child_name, const string& child_text)
    {
        HtmlElement e{child_name, child_text};
        root.elements.emplace_back(e);

        return *this;
    }

    string str() const
    {
        return root.str();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    HtmlBuilder builder("ul");
    builder.add_child("li", "apple").add_child("li", "orange");
    cout << builder.str() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit - `build` returns object instead of reference.

Comment: It looks like a circular dependency. Try moving declaration to header files, and function definition to cpp files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: Do you really need the `build` helper function on `HtmlElement`? That seems like a strange place to have it, especially since it returns a completely different type. It's a `static` method so it's not even necessary to put it there.

Comment: @dgrandm you don't need header and cpp file to solve, the important part is that the definition in which `HtmlBuilder` is used is after the definition of `HtmlBuilder` itself, but that could be done in file too (but that has nothing to to with header and cpp file, but with ordering)

Comment: @tadman In the video lecture I am watching the tutor used build function but did not compile the code. He did compiled the code without it and it worked fine. As I mentioned I am learning design patterns so I don't know if it's necessary or not.

Comment: @RahulKumar c++ has free functions, so using `static` is only rarely necessary.  In your code there is no indication why you want to use a `static` member function  for `HtmlBuilder& build(const string& root_name)` over a free function.

Comment: It looks extraneous and out of place. It's creating an annoying circular dependency in your code so unless you really need it, ditch it.

Comment: auto builder = HtmlElement::build("ul").add_child("", ""); This is how it will be used.

Comment: @tadman it works fine if I ditch the function but I want to know how to implement in the way mentioned in the question.

Comment: What is the reason of using `static` member function?

Comment: @Lexshard I want to use the function without creating an object.

Comment: @JaMiT not really. I was just trying to see if it will work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first comment points out you need to separate the *declaration* from the *definition*, otherwise the compiler is forced to tackle both at once, as they're given.

In your original code:

```
class HtmlBuilder;

class HtmlElement
{
    friend class HtmlBuilder;

public:
    static HtmlBuilder build(const string& root_name)
    {
        return {root_name};
    }
};
```

Here the compiler is being instructed to construct and return something it only knows by name, it knows nothing about how to create one of these. That's where you get the error. If instead you split this up and have a header file like:

```
// html_element.h

class HtmlBuilder;

class HtmlElement
{
    friend class HtmlBuilder;

public:
    static HtmlBuilder build(const string& root_name);
};
```

Here it's understood that something called `HtmlBuilder` is involved, and it's not clear what that is, but that's fine so long as it's *eventually* explained.

Then later in your *implementation file*:

```
#include "html_builder.h"
#include "html_element.h"

HtmlBuilder HtmlElement::build(const string& root_name)
{
    return {root_name};
}
```

This means it doesn't need to know exactly how to make one, it just has the general idea, and by the time your implementation is addressed it's all clear because the header file has been processed.

> Note that you should not return a reference to a temporary as JaMiT points out, so I've removed that from this code.

It's a good practice to split declarations (`.h` or `.hpp` as you prefer) from definitions/implementations (`.cpp)` to avoid traps like this. It also makes it a lot easier to find things when working with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand now why my code was not working. Also instead of breaking them in multiple files we can also write entire code in single file. First we need to define the "build" function and define it after the class "HtmlBuilder".

Comment: Breaking it up into multiple files is a strong convention mostly because any changes to one `.cpp` file don't require recompiling everything, saving a lot of time if you use a dependency-tracking build environment, which is really a must for non-trivial programs.